# Closed but not continuous operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, open-map, closed-graph, closed-map

I've found on a book an example of closed operator which is not continuous.
It is the following:
$$
 f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \quad f(t)= 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{t}  & \text{if $\, t \ne 0$} \\
0 & \text{if $\, t=0$}
\end{cases}
$$

Now, an equivalent definition of closedness says:

> Let $(X,\Vert . \Vert_X)$ and $(Y, \Vert . \Vert_Y)$ be two normed vector spaces and $\, f:X \rightarrow Y$ a function between them; then $f$ is *closed* if:
> $\qquad x_n \rightarrow x \, \land \, f(x_n) \rightarrow y \quad \Rightarrow \quad f(x)=y$

Recalling the previous example, let $\, x_n=\frac{1}{n}$. We have:
$$
 x_n \rightarrow 0 \quad \land \quad  f(x_n) = n \rightarrow +\infty \quad \text{BUT} \quad f(0)=0 \ne +\infty
$$

My explanation is that it is not correct to say that $f(x_n) = n \rightarrow +\infty$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Or better: according to the definition of convergence in normed vector space, $f(x_n)$ does **not** converge in $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, the definition of closed linear operator is fullfilled.
However, if we consider $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{*}$ the previous counterexample ($x_n = \frac{1}{n}$) is correct - since $+\infty \in \mathbb{R}^{*}$, so that $f(x_n) \rightarrow +\infty$ in $\mathbb{R}^{*}$. Therefore, $f$ is not closed in this last case.

Am I right?
If so, could you provide me a more significant example of closed but not continuous operator?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know **operator** means **linear operator**. Why is your $f$ linear?

Comment: The function $f$ you're considering is not linear, and $\mathbb R^*$ is not a vector space.

Comment: Of course, f cannot be linear - otherwise Closed Graph Theorem would be false.
Let me edit my question.

Comment: What are you looking for, it is here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344729/closed-unbounded-operator-with-domain-not-closed

Comment: @SigmaBoy I'm pretty sure the point is to find a closed, discontinuous linear map between vector spaces that are not *complete*, which is the essential assumption for the Closed Graph Theorem.